# How to create a N color cmap in plt py?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#e3eeee', '#3c0736'])
```

But when I plot it, I got this (see the legend):
I want to have the first color, as set in the list, but not a repeated 2 colors.

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you want.. can you elaborate?

Comment: How to set the colors on the legend sequential (related to each value/cat)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your problem correctly, but maybe this can help you.

If you want to have once the first color and then repeat the second, you could try to repeat it (more of an hack):

```
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['#e3eeee'] + ['#3c0736']*n)
```

where `n` is the number of times second color should repeat;

If instead your are looking to have a custom scale between two colors you could try:

```
cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Custom", ['#e3eeee'] + ['#3c0736'], N=n)
```

where `n` is the number of discrete cases in which you divided your population (7 in your case).

Comment: How to set the colors on the legend sequential color?

Comment: Sorry, could you be a bit more specific? Please, could you post your code or elaborate a bit more on the desired outcome?